# Cleaning up after av_frame_get_buffer

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, libav

There are two aspects of my question.  I'm using libav, ffmpeg, 3.1.

---

First, how do you appropriately dispose of a frame whose buffer has been allocated with `av_frame_get_buffer`? E.g.:

```
AVFrame *frame = av_frame_alloc();
frame->width = ...;
frame->height = ...;
frame->format = ...;
av_frame_get_buffer(frame, ...);
```

**Do any buffers have to be freed manually, beyond the call to `av_frame_free(frame)`?** The [documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.1/group__lavu__frame.html#ga6b1acbfa82c79bf7fd78d868572f0ceb) doesn't mention anything special, but in my experience the ffmpeg documentation often leaves out important details, or at least hides them in places far away from the obvious spots. I took a look at the code for `av_frame_free` and `av_frame_unref` but it branched out quite a bit and I couldn't quite determine if it covered everything.

---

Second, *if* something beyond `av_frame_free` needs to be done, then is there any catch-all way to clean up a frame if you *don't know* how its data has been allocated? For example, assuming `someBuffer` is already allocated with the appropriate size:

```
AVFrame *frame2 = av_frame_alloc();
frame2->width = ...;
frame2->height = ...;
frame2->format = ...;
av_image_fill_arrays(frame2->data, frame2->linesize, someBuffer, 
                     frame2->format, frame2->width, frame2->height, 1);
```

**Is there a way to free both `frame` and `frame2` in the above examples using the exact same code?** That is `frame` and its data should be freed, and `frame2` should be freed, but not `someBuffer`, since libav did not allocate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your first question - you don't need to do anything special to free buffers unless you are doing something funky (which you shouldn't). Image data is owned by `AVBuffer` which includes a reference counter; there are some references to that `AVBuffer` in a form of `AVBufferRef`. You can deal with `AVBufferRef` instances using relevant API - see `libavutil/buffer.h` for a description. `AVFrame` can hold references for the data it is pointing to, and generally you don't need to touch them as API will take care of that. You can use `av_frame_get_buffer` to allocate new buffers for the frame; you can use `av_frame_unref` or `av_frame_free` to "clean up" the frame or clean up and release it (which might not free image data because it is used by some other `AVFrame` or by an encoder); most if not all of other frame-related API is buffer-aware as well. Just make sure not to copy `AVBufferRef` pointers directly as that will circumvent reference counting - use `av_buffer_ref` instead.

To answer your second question - `av_frame_free` will do exactly that. It will release any `AVBufferRef`s attached to `AVFrame` and then it will free `AVFrame` itself. It will not touch anything that wasn't referenced by a buffer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (frame->data != NULL) av_freep(&frame->data)
```